# How to show facelets code

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, syntax-highlighting

I would like to show code like primefaces showcase:http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf

i use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/whatsnew.html)
,when i include facelets file in pre tag, it work fine.But when i show short code like:`<h:outputtext value="test"/>`
i code:

```
 <pre class="xml" name="code" ><h:outputtext value="test"/></pre>
```

it will display html code, the code after jsf compile and render.
i want jsf not compile  to html code.
If i use html special character, it seem to be more verbose to code.
How to config or take more code to do that.

**(Sorry for my English)**

Thank for your attention !

Comment: If you access to the link you've posted in your question and view the source code, you can see that they use `&lt;` and `&gt;` (and others) symbols to represent the JSF code.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: it seem to be more verbose to code

Comment: oh, i can not access http://showcase.omnifaces.org/ :|

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall or something else that blocks you to access there =\.

Comment: Can you access https://snapshot-omnifaces.rhcloud.com?

Comment: Thank @BalusC, i can, its seem to be i have to code &lt; for < character, i can not find a way to solve that :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing code directly inside the XHTML template, you really need to manually escape XML entities if you intend to present them as-is.

```
<pre class="xml" name="code">&lt;h:outputtext value="test"/&gt;</pre>
```

Hard to read? Perhaps for a starter, but not for an advanced.

Alternatively, you could store them somewhere in a `String` which can if necessary be populated from a text (properties) file or even a DB.

```
String code = "<h:outputText value=\"test\" />";
```

*(please note that you need to escape the doublequotes when you want to hardcode it as a Java String; you don't need to escape anything when it's stored in a text file or a DB)*

Facelets will automatically escape it:

```
<pre class="xml" name="code">#{bean.code}</pre>
```

Comment: I use Second approach, with #{bean.code}, code in bean is StringBuffer(and get from database), sorry @BalusC: so, no way to code in facelets(not use special html characters) ?

Comment: No. Just use find&replace the smart way if you've a lot of code which needs to be escaped from being interpreted as XML.

Comment: Thank, i'm really sad about that :|

Answer (score 2):

You need to exchange the < by &lt; and > by &gt;.

In else case it will be treated as HTML.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure that I understood you right, you want to have code? It's just a simple replace call on the string.

Comment: I would like to jsf not compile my facelets code like when i use <ui:include to include facelets file :)

Comment: @RongNK I would check the OmniFaces Showcase Code in order to get a real world example for this. Here's an example of [GenericEnumConverter page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter) and [it's open source code](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces-showcase/source/browse/WebContent/showcase/converters/GenericEnumConverter.xhtml)

Comment: Thank @Luiggi Mendoza, i will try now !

Comment: I don't use jfs, but this is a simple encoding problem. You must read the file and output it after an replace, else the server will execute the code.

Comment: Thank @rekire for your attetion, jsf compile component tag to html code, i just want jsf not compile some component tag to show them :)